# documentroot not correct?

Tags: html, apache

I cannot see an index.html in my site root. http://localhost/index.html does not work. Also 127.0.0.1/index.html and one other aa.local/index.html doesn't work either. But if I remove index.html to any of those above domains I get the Centos apache welcome screen. On the welcome page it says if it doesn't find an index in the /var/www/html directory it would show the welcome page. There is an index page in the root...that is what I am referring to above. I checked the httpd.conf file and the DocumentRoot is /var/www/html. If I put in another directory in the site root and try to load up any of the pages the page is not found. If I stop the server by saying:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl stop
```

When I reload any of the pages that didn't work it now gives an "unable to connect". The welcome page is unable to connect as well. I restart it using the above but change it to start and now I am back to where I started...index.html is not found and welcome page is back if I just do the domain root.

Any ideas?

Comment: what can you see when your index.html page is there? any error message? does your index.html have content?

Comment: @stratton - 404 - The requested URL /index.html was not found on this server.

Comment: Got it...Under System->Administration->Server settings->http I changed the Server Name to be my aa.local and then I under Virtual hosts tab and then I changed the Page Options I had it look for index.html or index.php...Then I restarted the server....I think just changing the server name should have done it

Comment: How do I mark this question as answered? I answered my own question in the previous post. I know I can delete it but it might be helpful for someone someday.

Comment: After 2 days you can mark your added answer as answered.

Comment: You can also delete it using the "delete" link

Comment: @Gerben Do not add `[SOLVED]` or something like that to the title. This is not a forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it...Under System->Administration->Server settings->http I changed the Server Name to be my aa.local and then I under Virtual hosts tab and then I changed the Page Options I had it look for index.html or index.php...Then I restarted the server....I think just changing the server name should have done it